# Просто получить get переменную из url

Tags: url, php, get

По ходу я отстал от жизни! Не могу найти связь, вроде и так просто, но не могу сделать - чувствую себя лузером: не могу проверить, есть ли какая переменная `get` в `url` и получить значение этого `get`... знаю, что проверяется `isset()`, но `isset ($_GET[''])` - ничего не дает...

Comment: foreach в ($_GET) 

а вся строка, если хочется парсить самому: 

     $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']

Comment: а поточнее на счет foreach?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.foreach.php

Comment: неправильно задал вопрос по ходу! а как превратить $_GET в массив или как записать средствами php $_GET в массив?

Comment: $_GET **уже** массив

Comment: выражение foreach($_GET as $key){
echo $key;
}
не дает никаких результатов!

Comment: потому что as $key=>$value

Comment: print_r($_GET);

Comment: глупая ошибка!(( спасибо! Вы мне очень помогли!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://mysite.com/blabla/bla.php?key1=val1

```
if (isset($_GET['key1'])) {
    var_dump($_GET['key1']); // val1
}
```

Comment: так я знаю, как получать! это если мы будем знать значение get, в данном случае, когда $_get['key1'] придаем значение какое-либо! а если мы такое значение url (foto.ru/gallery.php?boys)? как получить $_get['boys'] и значение "boys", если мы знаем только, что это значение $_get?

Comment: @tagir, в вашем случае "boys" - это не значение, а параметр, у которого значения нет.

Comment: Deonis, как получить этот параметр?

Comment: @tagir тогда вам больше подойдет foreach, в коментах советовали

Answer (score 2):

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r(array_keys($_GET), true).'</pre>';
```

---

```
foreach($_GET as $key => $value){
    echo $key .' = '.$value.'<br>';
}
```

---

Увидите:

- Имена (ключи) всех параметров, переданых GET-ом.
- Ключи и параметры GET

---

Что тут непонятно, и как помочь больше - без понятия

Comment: уже получил ответ на свой вопрос! Спасибо за внимание

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать просто

```
var_dump($_GET['']);
```

Comment: @Blackintenum жесть

Comment: уже получил ответ на свой вопрос! Спасибо за внимание